# Changing password problems in PHP

Tags: php, passwords

I am implementing a password change function in my android application and i coded the password hashing in my php file. User are able to change the password and the password are store in the database. When i try to log in with the email and the new password, it tell me incorrect password. Where did i do wrong for my php file?

This is my php file code:

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

function hashSSHA($newpassword) {
    $salt = mhash('sha512', rand());
    $salt = substr($salt, 0, 15);
    $encrypted = hash('sha512', $newpassword . $salt, true) . $salt;
    $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
    return $hash;
}

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['newpassword'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // TESTING HERE FOR STORING NEW PASSWORD INTO DATABASE
    $hash = hashSSHA($newpassword);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET encrypted_password = '$encrypted_password', salt = '$salt' WHERE email = '$email'");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully updated
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Password successfully changed";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Password change failed";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**EDIT**
THis is my decrypt function

```
// DECRYPTING user currentpassword
function checkhashSSHA($salt, $currentpassword) {

$hash = hash('sha512', $currentpassword . $salt, true) . $salt;
return $hash;
}
```

Comment: check that `mhash` library is installed or not

Comment: Describe how users passwords are verified when they try to log in.

Comment: This code is very vulnerable to SQL injection!

Comment: @diEcho where to check the mhash library?

Comment: lack of mhash would end in syntax error so no big deal

Comment: I think this is your problem `$salt = mhash('sha512', rand());
$salt = substr($salt, 0, 15);` Next time your user login, it generate another hash for the same password.

Comment: @jtheman i have another function to decrypt the password and check how the user credentials

Comment: @JvdBerg so how do i prevent it? i just started learning it

Comment: @ariefbayu but i use the same code for user registration and its working fine.

Comment: Easier to follow if you add the decrypt function... Otherwise I go for ariefbayu's comment...

Comment: @jtheman i updated the decrypt function

Comment: how do you handle the login process (both from android code and the accompanying php code)?

Comment: By calling the method from php file i learnt the method from androidhive

Comment: Instead of  `if($result)` you should use `if(mysql_affected_rows()===1)` , $result will be true also when there isn't any updated row. But however, we need to see the login-script too .

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of problems in your code.

First of all, SHA512 is not a good choice to hash passwords, because it is too fast. **Bcrypt** was designed especially to hash passwords, and is therefore slow (needs computing time). It's recommended to use a well established library like [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), and if you want to understand how to implement it, you can read this [article](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_bcrypt), where i tried to explain the most important points.

1) The first problem in your code probably is, that `mhash()` produces binary output for your salt. I don't know why you append it to your password-hash (that's not the way a salt should be applied), but the variable `$encrypted` will contain binary data afterwards.

2) This leads to the second problem, you insert the variable into your update statement. Inserting binary data into the sql will lead to an invalid statement. You should always escape data, before you add it to an sql statement, in your case use `mysql_escape_string()`.

3) The next problem is, that the mysql_* functions are deprecated, instead use mysqli or PDO for database access.

4) Another problem we have already encountered in problem 2 is, that without escaping your data, you are vulnerable to SQL-Injection attacks. Imagine what somebody can do with this user input...

WHERE email = '**`abc' OR email <> '`**'

...he could reset the password for all users at once!

That said, i really advise, that you reconsider to use Bcrypt.